# how to get the browser window size without the scroll bars

Tags: jquery

How to get the browser window size without the width and height of the scroll bars?

When I use this method, I'm playing with the width and height of the scroll bars to come up with 34.

```
     var $windowW = ($(window).width() - 34);
     var $windowH = ($(window).height() - 34);
     alert($windowW + "  " + $windowH); // THe results are width 1440 and 745 height
     $("body").css("width", $windowW);
     $("body").css("height", $windowH);
     $("body").css("border","1px solid green");
```

Comment: Why not just subtract the width of the scroll bars to whatever you get? That seems perfectly fine.

Comment: thanks but is there a way to get the size of the scroll bars?

Comment: HEY! - You have asked this twice now! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220450/how-to-put-a-border-around-the-browser-contetn-viewing-area-jquery

Comment: almost the same question, this question refers to getting the scroll bar height and width..

Comment: you should have edited your other question. you mentioned this problem in the other question. that in itself is duplication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getScrollBarDimensions(){
var elm = document.documentElement.offsetHeight ? document.documentElement : document.body,

    curX = elm.clientWidth,
    curY = elm.clientHeight,

    hasScrollX = elm.scrollWidth > curX,
    hasScrollY = elm.scrollHeight > curY,

    prev = elm.style.overflow,

    r = {
    vertical: 0,
    horizontal: 0
    };


    if( !hasScrollY && !hasScrollX ) {
    return r;
    }

elm.style.overflow = "hidden";

    if( hasScrollY ) {
    r.vertical = elm.clientWidth - curX;
    }

    if( hasScrollX ) {
    r.horizontal = elm.clientHeight - curY;
    }
elm.style.overflow = prev;


return r;
}
```

Running `getScrollBarDimensions();` on this page yields:

```
Object
horizontal: 0
vertical: 17
```

for me in google chrome, IE7, opera and firefox.

Comment: thanks Esailija, this looks like javascript, how do I get the return value for both vertical and horizantal using this function?

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene, `var dimensions = getScrollBarDimensions();` `alert( dimensions.horizontal +"\n"+ dimensions.vertical );`

Comment: @Esailija If I'm not mistaken this gets the dimensions of the document not of the window.

Comment: giving me 0 value for both horizontal and vertical even when my page has both vertical and horizontal scrolls.